# How to implement shadow for multiple pointLights in OpenGL ES 3.0 without using Geometry shader?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, emscripten

I am trying to implement shadows for multiple point lights in my scene. I was going through [this](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Point-Shadows) tutorial, but in this they have used a *cubemap and geometry shader* to store the depth values of fragments.

I am using emscripten and in their [documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/multimedia_and_graphics/OpenGL-support.html) they have said they support only OpenGL ES 3.0 and OpenGL ES 3.0 doesn't support geometry shaders, geometry shaders are supported from OpenGL ES 3.2. So is there any other way to implement shadows for multiple pointLights without using geometry shader.

Answer (score 1):

As already documented in that page:

> Normally we'd attach a single face of a cubemap texture to the framebuffer object and render the scene 6 times, each time switching the depth buffer target of the framebuffer to a different cubemap face.

Comment: But for that I have to render the scene *6 times*, that will be degrade the performance. Is there any other method?

Comment: On the GPU side of things, it's cheaper to render the scene 6 times than use geometry shaders ... are you sure rendering your shadow casters 6 times is really a problem?